# how to use BASH to convert the path to the home folder in the variable bash, in quotation marks into a working one

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terraform

Use the script, I am trying to create a directory in my home folder. Due to the specifics of integration with terraforms, parameters are passed in this way:

```
variable = "value"
```

It would be great If it worked like this:

```
variable = value
```

Examples:

```
$ pwd; eee="~/.ccc/ddd"; mkdir -p $eee; tree -a .
/home/user/test
.
└── ~
    └── .ccc
        └── ddd

3 directories, 0 files
```

or

```
$ pwd; eee="~/.ccc/ddd"; eee=$(echo $eee); mkdir -p $eee; tree -a .
/home/user/test
.
└── ~
    └── .ccc
        └── ddd

3 directories, 0 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `${HOME}` instead of `~`, it is more portable. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes) for details.